# How to unzip a single file?

Tags: go, unzip

I've found lots of examples on how to extract *all* files from .zip, but I can't figure out how to extract a single file without iterating over all files in the .zip file.

Is it possible in Go to extract a single file from a .zip archive without iterating over all files in the .zip file?

For example, if a zip file contained:

```
folder1/file1.txt
folder1/file2.txt
folder1/file3.txt
folder2/file1.txt
```

How would I extract only  `folder2/file1.txt`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please include your attempt, aim for a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using the [ExampleReader](https://golang.org/src/archive/zip/example_test.go) function with an added file name check that breaks the loop if the file name matches `folder2/file1.txt`. 

What I need to know is how to get the file handle without a loop.

Comment: `zip.Reader` provides you the content of the archive, the files as a slice. There is no helper method to get a file by name, you have to iterate over the files with a loop. You don't need to open / extract the files, but to find a file by name, you have to use a loop. What's wrong with using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`zip.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#Reader) provides you the content of the archive, the files as a *slice* (of [`zip.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#File)). There is no helper method to get a file by name, you have to iterate over the files with a loop. You don't need to open / extract the files, but to find a file by name, you have to use a loop.

For example:

```
r, err := zip.OpenReader("testdata/readme.zip")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer r.Close()

for _, f := range r.File {
    if f.Name != "folder2/file1.txt" {
        continue
    }

    // Found it, print its content to terminal:
    rc, err := f.Open()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(os.Stdout, rc)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    rc.Close()
    fmt.Println()
    break
}
```